# Select data between 2 datetime fields based on current date/time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table that has the following values (reduced for brevity)

| Period | Periodfrom | Periodto | Glperiodoracle | Glperiodcalendar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | JAN-FY2022 | JAN-2022 |
| 89 | 2022-01-29 00:00:00 | 2022-02-25 00:00:00 | FEB-FY2022 | FEB-2022 |
| 90 | 2022-02-26 00:00:00 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | MAR-FY2022 | MAR-2022 |
| 91 | 2022-04-02 00:00:00 | 2022-04-29 00:00:00 | APR-FY2022 | APR-2022 |
| 92 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 | 2022-05-27 00:00:00 | MAY-FY2022 | MAY-2022 |
| 93 | 2022-05-28 00:00:00 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | JUN-FY2022 | JUN-2022 |
| 94 | 2022-07-02 00:00:00 | 2022-07-29 00:00:00 | JUL-FY2022 | JUL-2022 |
| 95 | 2022-07-30 00:00:00 | 2022-08-26 00:00:00 | AUG-FY2022 | AUG-2022 |
| 96 | 2022-08-27 00:00:00 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00 | SEP-FY2022 | SEP-2022 |
| 97 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 2022-10-28 00:00:00 | OCT-FY2023 | OCT-2022 |

I want to make a stored procedure that when executed (without receiving parameters) will return the single row corresponding to the date between PeriodFrom and PeriodTo based on execution date.

I have something like this:

```
Select top 1 Period, 
       Periodfrom, 
       Periodto, 
       Glperiodoracle, 
       Glperiodcalendar
From Calendar_Period
Where Periodfrom <= getdate()
  And Periodto >= getdate()
```

I understand that using `BETWEEN` could lead to errors, but would this work in the edge cases taking in account seconds, right?

Comment: *"I understand that using between could lead to errors"* I assume you mean using `BETWEEN`. `BETWEEN` with dates, doesn't work as people expect because some think  `BETWEEN '20220616' AND '20220617'` would include the date and time `'2022-06-17T17:00:00'`, that that is *17 hours* after the upper boundary. If your periods are accurate to a second, the above will work; with the only problem being that you have omitted an `ORDER BY`, resulting in arbitrary results.

Comment: It may be your sample - but are you aware there are gaps where nothing would be returned? For example if GETDATE() returned ```2022-09-30 12:00:00``` then it would be AFTER the ```PeriodTo``` for ```Period``` 96 but BEFORE ```PeriodFrom``` for ```Period``` 97

Comment: Are your data types `datetime` but not actually containing a *time* component?

Comment: @MartinCairney yes, these are the edge cases I need to address,  that's why my current approach doesn't seem to work, for the gaps.

Comment: So what do you expect when there *is* a gap?

Comment: @Stu they don't but I can modify the type, should I change it to `DATE` instead of `DATETIME` and would that work then?

Comment: @Larnu to just use the date part of the columns, for example, if `getdate()` returns `2022-09-30 12:00:00` then it should still be counted as the 30th. so it should return period 96

Comment: So is a `periodfrom` of `2022-01-01 00:00:00` with a `periodto` of `2022-01-28 00:00:00` actually more like `2022-01-01 00:00:00` to `2022-01-28 23:59:59.999999999`? If you never store the time portion, then `date` for the `periodfrom`/`periodto` columns would make more sense, and then you can just `CAST`/`CONVERT` `GETDATE()` to a `date` too.

Comment: If you only require a *date* then only use a *date* type - then you can compare >=getdate() and < getdate() + 1 day casted as date.

Comment: @Larnu thank you, this sounds like the solution. thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like (i) your end date is inclusive (ii) the time portion is always 00:00. So the correct and most performant query would be:

```
where cast(getdate() as date) between Periodfrom and Periodto
```

It will, for example, return the first row when the current time is `2022-01-28 23:59:59.999`.